# matching and merging lines with awk & printing with Solaris

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to merge the matching pattern with *awk* on a Solaris system.

```
$ luxadm probe 
 No Network Array enclosures found in /dev/es

 Found Fibre Channel device(s): 
 Node WWN:2000000c50f1c8da Device Type:Disk device 
 Logical Path:/dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s2 
 Node WWN:2000000c50f1d9c9 Device Type:Disk device 
 Logical Path:/dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s2
```

Note - While I am trying with *awk*, it takes Only one line merging from last.

```
$ luxadm probe |awk '/Node/{n=$2}/Logical/{l=$2} END {print n,l}' 
 WWN:2000000c50f1d9c9 Path:/dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s2
```

While the output expected is:

```
WWN:2000000c50f1d9c9 Path:/dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s2
WWN:2000000c50f1c8da Path:/dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer which isn't mentioned yet in `awk`

```
awk '/Node/{n=$2; getline; print n " "$2; next}' filename
```

- `/Node/` # Look for pattern Node and store the second field in `n` variable `n=$2`
- `getline` # Move to the next line (This is where `Logical` line starts), print what's stored in `n` variable and then second field of the next line.
- `next` # Stop processing current record and move to the next one.

Comment: Your codes works.. can you explain please , I wana learn..

$ luxadm probe | awk '/Node/{n=$2; getline; print n " "$2; next}'
WWN:2000000c50f1c8da Path:/dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s2
WWN:2000000c50f1d9c9 Path:/dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s2

Comment: @Costas - Your last two codes working perfectly .. Could you pleas explain ...

$ luxadm probe | awk '/Node/{printf "%s ", $2}/Logical Path/{print $2}'
WWN:2000000c50f1c8da Path:/dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s2
WWN:2000000c50f1d9c9 Path:/dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s2

$ luxadm probe | awk '/Node/{wwn=$2}/Logical Path/{print wwn,$2}'
WWN:2000000c50f1c8da Path:/dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s2
WWN:2000000c50f1d9c9 Path:/dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s2

Comment: @Karn  Well many answers here are correct. I think you just need to get your head around and see if you understand it. All answers are explained to a great extent imo.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's faililng is because you are only printing the variables you capture once, in an `END{}` block. This means that only the last two will be printed. @Costas already gave you a more elegant approach, but you could also use the same logic you were trying with a small change:

```
awk '{ if(/Node/){
        if(length(n)){print n,l} ## if we have an n, print them
        n=$2
        }
        if(/Logical/){l=$2}
      } 
        END {print n,l}'
```

Alternatively, you could use other tools:

1. GNU grep/perl

   ```
   luxadm probe |  grep -Po '^\s*(Node|Logical)\s*\K.*?(\s|$)' file | 
       perl -lne '$. % 2 ? printf : print'
   ```
2. Perl

   ```
   luxadm probe |  
     perl -ne 'chomp;if(s/.*(WWN:.*?)\s.*/$1 / || s/.*(Path:.*?)$/$1\n/){print}'
   ```

Comment: Still its not giving the desired as it getting only 4th field.. I am a learner so trying to fight with this puzzle with your expertise guys..

$ luxadm probe | awk -F":| " '/Node/{printf "%s ", $3":"$4}/Logical Path/{print $4}'

Disk device:
Disk device:

Comment: @Karn did you try the one (ones, now, see update) in my answer? The one you gave in the comment above will fail, yes, but is not the one I posted.

Comment: @Karn (please answer comments in the place they were asked, I don't get pinged otherwise). I know you showed us the output of `luxadm` but your comment to Costas's answer mentioned "you have mail in /var/mail/root". Is that in the input? If you try these and they fail, please edit your question and include the specific error messages/output you get. That way, we can correct it.

Comment: @terdon  a great `perl` one!

Comment: @terdon - my apologies, going out of the bay while answering , may be because I am a first time user on the site..Moreover I tried your code which is throwing errors .. please see below..
$ perl -ne 'chomp;if(s/.*(WWN:.*?)\s.*/$1 / || s/.*(Path:.*?)$/$1\n/){print}'

^C$

[2] +  Done(2)                 luxadm probe |  grep -Po '^\s*(Node|Logical)\s*\K.*?(\s|$)' file | perl -lne '$. % 2 ? printf : print'
$

Comment: @Karn no reason to apologize, I'm just showing you the ropes :).  Hang on though, are you using Solaris? If so, please edit your question and mention that, my grep solution won't work on Solaris, it needs GNU grep.

Comment: @terdon, Yes I am using solaris and I have edited the same.I appreciate your mentoring going with this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `sed`, in my opinion. In the first place, it will usually outperform `awk`, and, in this case, it offers a more simple solution overall:

```sh
sed -n 'N;s/Node \([^ ]*\).*Logical/\1/p' <infile
```

...which, given your example data, prints...

```
 WWN:2000000c50f1c8da Path:/dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s2
 WWN:2000000c50f1d9c9 Path:/dev/rdsk/c1t0d0s2
```

For each line read, `sed` also gets the `N`ext appended to pattern space following an inserted `\n`ewline delimiter. So the above `s///`ubstitution spans two lines, and prints the two fields you want separated only by a space and only when a match is found.

The above `sed` syntax should be fully portable to any POSIX system.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `awk`

```
awk -v RS=' Node ' -v FS=' Logical Path:| ' '/WWN/{print $1,$6}'
```

Other (may be simple)

```
awk -F":| " '/Node/{printf "%s ", $3":"$4}/Logical Path/{print $4}'
```

with remain `Path:`

```
awk '/Node/{printf "%s ", $2}/Logical Path/{print $2}'
```

or

```
awk '/Node/{wwn=$2}/Logical Path/{print wwn,$2}'
```

And GNU `sed` at last:

```
sed -n '/WWN/{s/^\s*\S* *\|\( \S*\)\{3\}\s*$//g;N;s/\n\s*\S*//;p}'
```

Comment: its does not work for the situation...
$ luxadm probe | awk -v RS=' Node ' -v FS=' Logical Path:| ' '/WWN/{print $1,$6}'
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
you have mail in /var/mail/root

Comment: @Karn in that case, please edit your question and include the entire output of `luxadm probe`.